# Change Windows keyboard layout using c#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard, pinvoke, culture

Is it possible to change the Windows OS keyboard layout (from azerty to querty for example) using C# ?
(for the entire OS, not just the process of the current application)

Do i have to use PInvoke or is there a simpler api/way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a single call:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

**Sample**:

For Adding and Activating U.S. English Dvorak layout, use "00010409".

```
LoadKeyboardLayout("00010409", 1)
```

MSDN:

> Beginning in Windows 8: The input locale identifier is loaded for the
>   entire system. This function has no effect if the current process does
>   not own the window with keyboard focus.

Meaning: Your window must be in focus otherwise the function has no effect.

Full documentation from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadkeyboardlayouta?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my keyboard didn't change to qwerty when i applied this.

Comment: Thanks !, it works now. The problem i had when i tested it was the VS break points, they forced a switch of focus towards VS

Comment: Not works for console app.